# How do I render a cached JSONP view in Django

Tags: python, django, json, caching, django-views

I'm querying a db of election info and spitting them out in JSONP to use for some ajax/jQuery widgets we are creating.

What I'm wanting to do however is cache the view so that a new request isn't coming in every time the widget is rendered.

I'm running into 2 issues though.

1. Which method of caching should I use to render this view so that the database isn't getting hit hard.
2. I need to render the view as JSONP which means I need the callback variable to be dynamic (which it current'y is with my script but I'm afraid it wouldn't be with a cached view).

Here's what my code looks like.

```
from models import race
from models import candidates
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import simplejson


def data(request):

    data = []
    races = race.objects.all()

    for election in races:

        race_candidate = candidates.objects.filter(race__id=election.pk)

        candidate_info = []
        for n,candidate in enumerate(race_candidate):
            candidate_values = {
                "name":candidate.name,
                "percent":candidate.percent,
                "totalvotes":candidate.totalvotes,
                "partyname":candidate.partyname,
                "partyabbrv":candidate.partyabbrv,
                }

            candidate_info.append(candidate_values)

        race_values = {
            "title":election.title,
            "description":election.description,
            "priority":election.priority,
            "decided":election.decided,
            "candidates":candidate_info,
            }

        data.append(race_values)

    json_races = '{"races":' + simplejson.dumps(data) + '}'

    if("callback" in request.GET.keys()):
        callback = request.GET["callback"]
    else:
        callback = None

    if(callback):
        response = HttpResponse("%s(%s)" % (
                callback,
                simplejson.dumps(data)
                ), mimetype="application/json"
            )
    else:
        response = HttpResponse(json_races, mimetype="application/json")
    return response
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use the [low-level cache API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api) with whichever cache backend you like.

```
from django.core.cache import cache

...

CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600      # choose your timeout

def data(request):
    jsonstring = cache.get('elections')

    if jsonstring is None:
        data = [{
                "title": election.title,
                "description": election.description,
                "priority": election.priority,
                "decided": election.decided,
                "candidates": [
                      {
                         "name": candidate.name,
                         "percent": candidate.percent,
                         "totalvotes": candidate.totalvotes,
                         "partyname": candidate.partyname,
                         "partyabbrv": candidate.partyabbrv,
                    } for candidate in election.candidates_set.all()
                  ],
                } for election in race.objects.all()]

        jsonstring = simplejson.dumps(data)
        cache.set('elections', jsonstring, CACHE_TIMEOUT)

    callback = request.GET.get('callback')

    if callback:
        response = HttpResponse("%s(%s)" % (callback, jsonstring),
                                mimetype="application/json")
    else:
        response = HttpResponse('{"races":' + jsonstring + '}',
                                mimetype="application/json")

    return response
```

In your `settings.py`, configure `CACHE` according to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#setting-up-the-cache). The memory backend is the simplest, memcached is probably the best.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Is there anyway to implement a cache buster?

Comment: Sure, just add something like "if jsonstring is None or request.GET.get('nocache'):" or make the cache key dependent on the query string.